# What is a positive, right-tailed random variable that can be set to have mean $0.5$, variance $0.01$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am wondering if there exists a right-tailed positive random variable that can be set to have a mean of $0.5$, variance $0.01$. The normal distribution will generate negative values, and it looks impossible to use the Gamma or the Log-Normal for these purposes. Would anyone have any ideas if there exist distributions for which it has a heavy right tail? Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution ?

Comment: I don't understand how it's "impossible" to use the Gamma distribution for this purpose. Based on the parametrization [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Characterization_using_shape_k_and_scale_%CE%B8), we have $k\theta = 0.5$ and $k\theta^2 = 0.01$, so that $\theta = 0.02$ and $k = 25$.

Comment: "Heavy" right tail could be a problem, since it would lead to a large variance.  You need a distribution around 0.5 which is narrow (roughly 0.1) to get that small a variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a density with a power tail:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2sx}\exp\left(-\left|\frac{\ln x - m}{s}\right|\right)$$

for the values $m=-0.7116862$ and $s=0.1355204$. The right tail decays like $x^{-8.3789}$, which is not very heavy but still slower than exponential.